# (jQuery) Calling function on mobile, but jQuery animations not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that has a clickable option. When that option is clicked, some functions run and the page's display changes. the button is something like this:

```
<table id="topBar">
  ...
  <td id="menuHeader" (click)=callMenu()>
    <img id="menus" style="height: 25px" src="../../assets/Menu.svg">
    <h2 style="margin-top: 10px;" id="foo"> Foo </h2>
  </td>
</table>
```

What matters here is the callMenu() function:

```
callMenu() {
  alert('foo');
  if ($("#sidebar").position().left == -200) {
    $('#sidebar').animate({ left: "0px" }, 200);
    $("#darken").show();
  } else {
    $('#sidebar').animate({ left: "-200px" }, 200);
    $("#darken").hide();
  }
}
```

This function works fine on PC, the problem is happening on mobile browsers. The alert `foo` works, what shows me the function is being called. But the jquery is not acting upon the page, thus not calling the sidebar. 

I've read in another question that this could be cause by an error on the console, that the mobile browser is unable to recover, but my console has no errors, only this warning:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
>   directive. If you set disabled to true
>         when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
>         you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
>
> ```
>   Example: 
>   form = new FormGroup({
>     first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
>     last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
>   });
> ```

But even after removing this problematic form, the problem persists.

What am I doing wrong here? Or doesn't jQuery supports this on mobile?

Comment: `if ($("#sidebar").position().left == -200)` are you sure this is true on mobile when clicking? put some alerts in the if and else  and see what happens.

Comment: `if ($("#sidebar").position().left == -200) {` is a bad way of checking what's actually the elements *state*. Use a variable like `var sideBarHidden = true;` for the check and change it accordingly.

Comment: @Michelangelo as dumb as it looks, for some readon, ONLY on mobile, the initial position was -199,9999998! I changed the condition to `if ($("#sidebar").position().left < 0)` and it's working fine. You can post that as an answer, i'll accept

Comment: @CH4B Ok, will do. Yeah, the calculation can be off on mobile browsers. And your solution is better now. You only want to know if it is on the screen or off the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems that on mobile the calculation of the position is wrong. Check if the `if` statement returns true `if ($("#sidebar").position().left == -200)`. If not the calculation is wrong on mobile and you should reconsider how you want to check when te sidebar is hidden.